# How to make qupid consumer exlusive using apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, amqp, qpid

I am trying to connect single qpid broker via to clients.
I want only one of these two client should listen the qpid queue.
I am trying this with apache camel

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe QPID supports exclusive consumer on queues. An alternative option is to deploy your Camel route in Karaf in a primary+failover setup. The failover karaf container will be running in a "warm" mode where the Camel route is not started. If the primary fails, the failover will take over and start up all Camel routes. Works great for Highly Available database and file pollers as well!

ref: [Karaf HA / Cluster setup](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_ha_failover_and_cluster)